# How do I search an Android Custom Listview with an edit text

Tags: android

hi I've tried so many different ways of trying to get this darn search bar working that I really need some help.

I got close once but it kept crashing when ever I put any thing in the edit text.

my list view rows are comprised of 2x text views which are populated by string arrays in the strings.xml file and 1 50x50 image.

here's my adapter code any help would be very well appreciated :) any unused instances were for the other search trials and I have removed the various non working search methods

```
     ListView l;
     AdapterHand mAdapter;
     EditText inputSearch;
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kalosdex);
        l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        l.setAdapter(new AdapterHand(this));
     }

 class viewHolder {
    ImageView myImage;
    TextView myTitle;
    TextView myDescription;

    viewHolder(View v) {
        myTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        myDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}

class SingleRow {
    String title;
    String description;
    int balls;

    SingleRow(String title, String description, int balls) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.balls = balls;


    }

}

class AdapterHand extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<SingleRow> list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
    Context context;

    AdapterHand(Context c) {
        context = c;
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        Resources res = c.getResources();
        String[] title = res.getStringArray(R.array.kalostitles);
        String[] description = res.getStringArray(R.array.kalosids);
        int[] balls = {
                R.drawable.kalos001, R.drawable.kalos002, R.drawable.kalos003,
                R.drawable.kalos004, R.drawable.kalos005, R.drawable.kalos006,
                R.drawable.kalos007, R.drawable.kalos008, R.drawable.kalos009,
                R.drawable.kalos010, R.drawable.kalos011, R.drawable.kalos012,
                R.drawable.kalos013, R.drawable.kalos014, R.drawable.kalos015,
                R.drawable.kalos016, R.drawable.kalos017, R.drawable.kalos018,
                R.drawable.kalos019, R.drawable.kalos020, R.drawable.kalos021,
                R.drawable.kalos022, R.drawable.kalos023, R.drawable.kalos024,
                R.drawable.kalos025, R.drawable.kalos026, R.drawable.kalos027,
                R.drawable.kalos028, R.drawable.kalos029, R.drawable.kalos030,
                R.drawable.kalos031, R.drawable.kalos032, R.drawable.kalos033,
                R.drawable.kalos034, R.drawable.kalos035, R.drawable.kalos036,
                R.drawable.kalos037, R.drawable.kalos038, R.drawable.kalos039,
                R.drawable.kalos040, R.drawable.kalos041, R.drawable.kalos042,
                R.drawable.kalos043, R.drawable.kalos044, R.drawable.kalos045,
                R.drawable.kalos046, R.drawable.kalos047, R.drawable.kalos048,
                R.drawable.kalos049, R.drawable.kalos050, R.drawable.kalos051,
                R.drawable.kalos052, R.drawable.kalos053, R.drawable.kalos054,
                R.drawable.kalos055, R.drawable.kalos056, R.drawable.kalos057,
                R.drawable.kalos058, R.drawable.kalos059, R.drawable.kalos060,
                R.drawable.kalos061, R.drawable.kalos062, R.drawable.kalos063,
                R.drawable.kalos064, R.drawable.kalos065, R.drawable.kalos066,
                R.drawable.kalos067, R.drawable.kalos068, R.drawable.kalos069,
                R.drawable.kalos070, R.drawable.kalos071, R.drawable.kalos072,


        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 72; i++) {
            list.add(new SingleRow(title[i], description[i], balls[i]));
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


        View row = convertView;
        viewHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, null, false);
            holder = new viewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
            Log.d("MetaDex", "Creating");
        } else {
            holder = (viewHolder) row.getTag();
            Log.d("MetaDex", "Recycling");
        }

        SingleRow temp = list.get(i);


        holder.myTitle.setText(temp.title);
        holder.myDescription.setText(temp.description);
        holder.myImage.setImageResource(temp.balls);
        return row;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question , you want a search filter when you enter text.
Here is my suggestion , Instead of using an EditText , use AutoCompleteTextView , here you can use input search.

This is the XML code for an AutoCompleteTextView,

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="Enter Text"
       >
```

This is the java code for the drop down list.

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, stringName);

        final AutoCompleteTextView Text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteText);
        Text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        Text.setThreshold(1);
        Text.setAdapter(adapter);        
        Text.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but not quite what I was looking for, essentially I need to search my list view of 721 items/rows and have it show the items corresponding to what the user types in the edit text.